# WebRTC in javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, webrtc

I am trying to make WebRTC an object in javascript for easier use.
Since javascript is executed on my side, i get an error saying Firebase is not defined. 
So I called the script source using the following code;

```
///in this section I am trying to get the firebase.js 
var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', "https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js");
head.appendChild(script);
```

After that I try to get a reference to FireBase database and create my own

```
var dbRef = new Firebase("https://webrtcdemo.firebaseIO.com/");///this is the line i get the error
var roomRef = dbRef.child("rooms");
```

To sum up my question is it possible to use WebRTC(reference Firebase) in javascript? If so how is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code with `new Firebase(...`? Make sure Firebase is loaded before using it.

Comment: Yes it is possible, [here is an experiment utilizing firebase and webrtc datachannels](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/part-of-screen-sharing/firebase/)

Comment: @digitalfresh thats all the code for Firebase I am just trying to execute the link so I can reference the Firebase database

Comment: @BenjaminTrent Is that using javascript? Because it seems like its being used from .html

Comment: @beavis578 Are you making sure that Firebase is loaded before using it?

Comment: What? Just because it references `div`s does not mean that it magically uses Firebase without javascript(which is not possible).

Comment: @digitalfresh, thats my problem the error says firebase is not defined, which I am guessing its not loading at all. Thats what I am trying to figure out how to do.

Comment: @BenjaminTrent I used the Webrtc example only thing I have changed so far is that instead of using <script></script> I used var head=....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're loading code from javascript, you need to wait for it to load before continuing:

```
// define onload handler
function onFirebaseLoad() {
  var dbRef = new Firebase("https://webrtcdemo.firebaseIO.com/");
  var roomRef = dbRef.child("rooms");
  // ...
}

// load the code
var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.onload = onFirebaseLoad;
script.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(script.readyState == 'complete') onFirebaseLoad();
};
script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
script.setAttribute('src', "https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js");
head.appendChild(script);
```